# angularjs closeable div does not close after clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm following the [blur admin](http://akveo.com/blur-admin-mint/#/ui/alerts) UI to display the alert after button clicked. However, the closeable alert message does not closed when I clicked on the close button.

I want to be able to close the alert message and turn s`cope.added = false`.
Any help please?

Here is how my code looks like:

in HTML:

```
  <div ng-show="added" class="alert bg-success closeable" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span
                aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <strong>Added</strong> Successfully!
    </div>
 <div style="text-align: center">
        <button type="submit" ng-click="display()"
                class="btn btn-danger">add
        </button>
    </div>
```

in JS:

```
$scope.added = false;
$scope.display=  function () {
$scope.added = true;

}
```

thanks

Comment: your first button needs to have click function that can set that boolean flag to false and that will result in hiding the whole div block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ng-click` to your X (close) button:

```
<button 
    type="button" 
    class="close" 
    aria-label="Close" 
    ng-click="close()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">
        &times;
    </span>
</button>
```

And then add the `close()` function to the controller:

```
$scope.close = function(){
    $scope.added = false;
}
```

Comment: Could he also write the flag change inline as ng-click="added = !added" or ng-click="added = false"? Or is the function a necessary part of getting the flag to change?

Comment: Yes, both suggestions perfectly fine. I always prefer to keep any changes to scope in the controller though (however simple), just so it's all in the same place. Strictly speaking the view should only be responsible for displaying values on the scope, it shouldn't change anything.